# Android location accuracy

Tags: android, android-location

I have the following code implemented to retrieve location values on Android:

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

On Android 2.3 and 4.1 this works great and returns updates at 180 samples per hour with a resolution down to 100m or less.

However, on Android 4.3 something has changed so this only provides updates at 5 samples per hour and a resolution at 2km. I haven't tested on later versions.

What has changed? Is it possible to return to the old accuracy levels again? I don't want to force GPS for power reasons. The app has `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permissions.

I have been testing this on a Samsung S3 if it makes a difference.

Comment: try turning on the WiFi on your S3, It will give you more frequent updates and with better accuracy. (Network Provider also uses WiFi networks for getting a fix).

Answer (score 1):

Use Google's LocationServices API instead:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Answer (score 1):

**LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER** do not provide accurate location it provides you the location according to the cell tower you connected,sometimes it provides location with accuracy of 100m sometimes with 2-3km,if you do not want to get the location from gps due to power reasons i would suggest you to use fused location provides as this is an efficient and effective way to get the location on android and Google also recommends this,you can read more here in this example http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html